# How does UI thread know about data on another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I came across a situation which puzzled me at work today which I have simplified in the following code. This code builds and throws no exceptions during debug.

Suppose I have a WinForms app. In my main UI thread I spin off another thread which instantiates an object which in turn holds reference to a control (label1 in my example). I then call a method on my object (SetLabelText) which passes it's execution back onto the UI thread if required.

What stumped me was how, when we are back in the UI thread and executing SetLabelText, is .net CLR able to access the labelText variable when we are executing on a thread (ie the UI thread) which did not create the instance of Thing.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate void DoSomethingDelegate();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var t = new Thread(DoSomethingWithThing);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void DoSomethingWithThing()
    {
        var thing = new Thing(this.label1);
        thing.SetLabelText();
    }
}

public class Thing
{
    private Label label;
    private string labelText = "new value";
    delegate void SetLabelTextDelegate();

    public Thing(Label label)
    {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public void SetLabelText()
    {
        if (this.label.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var setLabelDel = new SetLabelTextDelegate(SetLabelText);
            this.label.Invoke(setLabelDel);
        }
        else
        {
            this.label.Text = this.labelText;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

References to objects are available on any thread.

Threads are not sand-boxed from each other. They share resources unless you explicitly create non-shared resources.

Threads are execution contexts. Think of your application as a kitchen and each thread as a chef. They can work at the same time but if two of them try to use the same knife at the same time, things get messy. This is why c# has the `lock` keyword and other synchronization mechanisms.

WinForms has restrictions on access to controls because of the way WinForms renders.